# Confusion regarding YouTube API Dev Key

Tags: youtube-api

I'm currently working on an application that uses the YouTube API v2.0.  I'm following the documentation outlined here.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading

I have chosen the OAuth 2.0 method for obtaining an access token as documented here.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Server_Side_Web_Applications_Flow

In the OAuth 2.0 documentation they have you register an app in the APIs Console.  However in the direct uploading for v2.0 document they tell you need to include a header with a developer key that you can get by registering a product in the Product Dashboard.

I am not seeing how the registered product in the Product Dashboard is connected to the registered app in the APIs Console, it would seem to make more sense to use the client ID provided in the API console.  Is the documentation outdated or something?

Answer (score 0):

Someone may be able to explain it better than me, but AFAIK you need to do both. the OAuth2 client ID is needed so that you can allow users to authorize your app, and will allow you to perform oAuth2 requests with any API you turn on ... it is the key that will allow you to get access tokens as needed. These access tokens are then passed in the header. It is not Youtube specific, necessarily, although you can generate different client IDs that can perform oAuth2 requests on different APIs, based on your varying apps' needs.

The developer key is a separate key from the product dashboard that identifies your app uniquely to Youtube (not to the oAuth service). It is Youtube specific.

So in essence, the two keys aren't necessarily connected, as they have two different functions, but they work together when you make an upload request.

I'm happy to be corrected, though.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the case.